# First Order Linear Difference Equations -- Can't understand how the equation is derived

Tags: recurrence-relations

For the case n > n0 + 1, I can't comprehend how *Iterating*
\begin{equation} 
y[n] = \lambda y[n-1] 
\end{equation} yields
\begin{equation}
y[n] = \left(\lambda\right)^{n-n_0}\frac{b \;}{\lambda} \;\;\; n > n_0.
\end{equation}

For the entire description, please visit [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUNLV.png) page.

Comment: Note that they have shown that $y[n_0+1]=b$, after which $y[n]=\lambda y[n-1]=\ldots=\lambda^k y[n-k]$ whence $y[n]=\lambda^{n-(n_0+1)}y[n_0+1]=\lambda^{n-n_0}\frac b\lambda$ for $n\gt n_0$

Comment: @PrasunBiswas Got it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas And -- In the case \lambda \lt 1, how is it that \begin{equation}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} y[n] = y[{\infty}]= 0.
\end{equation}

Comment: Because if $0\lt\lambda\lt 1$, the map $n\mapsto\lambda^n$ is strictly decreasing approaching $0$ asymptotically, ie, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\lambda^n=0$ for $0\lt\lambda\lt 1$

Comment: @PrasunBiswas Great! Can't thank you enough.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128859/discussion-between-aarush-aggarwal-and-prasun-biswas).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the link you provided we have $y[n_0+1]=b$, thus, for $n>n_0$ we may write
$$
y[n]= \lambda y[n-1]= \lambda^2 y[n-2]= \ldots= \lambda^{n-n_0-1} y[n-(n-n_0-1)]= \frac{\lambda^{n-n_0}}{\lambda}y[n_0+1]= (\lambda)^{n-n_0}\frac{b}{\lambda}. 
$$